# Share via Facebook Messenger App - ionic framework / Cordova apache

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I need to share a link from my app to the Facebook Messenger App, because I need to send to specific contacts. I tried the plugin [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin] and it looks like that's possible on Android, example:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareVia('com.facebook.orca', 'Message via FB', null, null, null, function(){console.log('share ok')}, function(msg) {alert('error: ' + msg)});
```

This seems to work but when I select the contacts and I press the send button, it freeze with loading popUp, and I can't find the solution.

I need a solution for this plugin or a similar one. The objective is to share via Facebook Messenger on Android and iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will not be able to prefill the message. It is not technically possible and even if it was it is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: @WizKid but a link is allowed and is all I need. I edited my question changing text by link. What I need isn't strange, a lot of apps include this function.

Comment: @benLIVE Any one got solution ?

Comment: @Muhsin use shareVia 'facebook'... instead of 'com.facebook.orca' or check documentation if it was changed https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: @benLIVE :but it is not working in iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareVia('com.facebook.orca', 'The message', null, null, 'https://www.google.com/', function () { console.log('share ok') }, function (errormsg) { alert(errormsg) });
```

Comment: @Julien Did you get any solution?